Characteristic curves of partial differential equation $(2x+u)u_x + (2y+u)u_y = u$.
The characteristic curves of PDE
$$(2x+u)u_x + (2y+u)u_y = u$$
passing through $(1,1)$ for any arbitrary initial values prescribed on a non-characteristic curve are given by:
$1.$ $x=y$
$2.$ $x^2 + y^2 = 2$
$3.$ $x + y = 2$
$4.$ $x^2 + y^2 - xy = 1$
I am following Y. Pinchover book of the partial differential equation. I tried as
The characteristic equations are:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = 2x + u, \quad \frac{dy}{dt} = 2y + u, \quad \frac{du}{dt} = u.
$$

Solving $\frac{du}{dt} = u$:
$$
u = C_1 e^t.
$$

Solving $\frac{dx}{dt} = 2x + u$:
$$
x = -{C_1} e^t + C_2 e^{2t}.
$$

Solving $\frac{dy}{dt} = 2y + u$:
$$
y = -C_1 e^t + C_3 e^{2t}.
$$


Now I am having a problem with how to use the given condition that passes through $(1,1)$ for any arbitrary initial values prescribed on a non-characteristic curve. We choose for initial condition $t=0, x_0(s)= 1, y_0(s)=1, u_0(s)=?$, but unable to work further. please help. Thank you. I am not doing another method like Finding characteristic curve of PDE .

What can you say at least about $C_1,C_2$ and $C_3$ are they surely non-null and or inequal ?

@EDX I think $C_2= C_3$ so $x=y?$

Can you prove it ?

Why do you think $C_2=C_3$? (By the way, there is a small mistake in items 2 and 3: it should be $e^{2t}$ instead of $e^{-2t}$.)

@Gonçalo when $t=0$ we have $C_2=C_3$ as $x=y=1$.
